# Statistics - Defective rods problem

Tags: probability

***Problem :***

*At a factory that produces metallic rods, 20% of them aren't of good quality. The quality tests are of 90% reliability when the rod is of good quality and of 80% reliability when the rod is of bad quality.*

**a)** *What percentage of the rods produced will be destroyed (deemed not of good quality)*

**b)** *What percentage of the rods destroyed are actually of good quality ?*

***Attempt/Thought :***

I would start by naming each possibility :

$E$ the possibility of the rod being of bad quality : $P(E) = 0.2$

$E^c$ the possibility of the rod being of good quality : $P(E^c) = 1 - P(E) = 0.8$

$A$ the event of being **deemed** of bad quality

Then we have :

$P(E^c | A) = 0.1$

$P(E |A)  = 0.8$

Now, I feel like especially **(b)** is solved by using *Bayes-Theorem* but I am not sure and I cannot really proceed in solving this problem. I know this is 99.9% an easy Probabilities Problem but I missed most of the semester due to illness so I am trying to make a race to prepare as good as I can for the exams and I would really, really appreciate any help or thorough solution on such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, you've put what you were told into symbols incorrectly. You know that if a rod is good quality then it gets destroyed with probability $0.1$, i.e. the probability of being destroyed given good quality is $0.1$. In symbols this is $P(A\mid E^c)=0.1$.

The question asks for $P(A)$ and $P(E^c\mid A)$. Since a destroyed rod is either good quality or bad quality,
$$P(A)=P(A\cap E)+P(A\cap E^c)=P(A\mid E)P(E)+P(A\mid E^c)P(E^c).$$
The other part can now be written in terms of two things you've already worked out:
$$P(E^c\mid A)=\frac{P(A\cap E^c)}{P(A)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the fast and clear answer mate !

Answer (score 1):

For a), you can use the law of total probability. Let $D$ be the event of any rod being destroyed. We get:
\begin{align}
P(D)&=P(D\mid E)P(E)+P(D\mid E^c)P(E^c)=\\
&=0.8\cdot0.2+0.1\cdot0.8=0.24
\end{align}
This directly yields the answer for b), which is $0.08/0.24 = \frac 13\approx 33.3\%$.